# Inapp purchase receipt validation crash in Live

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

My first version of the app was working well both when live as well as in sandbox..now the second version is crashing after downloading from Appstore. The second version worked well in sandbox mode for both development and ad-hoc. The [applicaiton](https://buy.itunes.apple.com/VerifyReceipt) went live and now it's crashing

worked well when it was in [Sandbox](https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/VerifyReceipt)

Comment: The crash report says its a EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
triggered at thread 7 -
Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x17023a060 :: NSOperation 0x174248bb0 (QOS: LEGACY)
Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue might be with the receipt handling code,Please handle the null/empty array/dictionary part correctly ,You might be receiving receipts details as null or empty Array/dictionary in some cases.
Check it

Comment: Yea you said it bro,
by checking if the response had any objects did the trick..
reponseArray>0 did it

Comment: Hello - I am having the same issue.  When you say check the array response if greater than > 0... where in the response do I check this?